# Solving a second-order nonhomogenous differential equation involving trig functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I was trying to find the Eqn. of Motion for the following system (a jiggle pendulum):

[image]

Using the Lagrangian and the Euler-Lagrange-Eqn., I ended up with: $$\ddot{\theta} + \frac{g}{l}\sin{\theta} = -\frac{1}{l}\ddot{x_O}\cos{\theta}$$

While it is much easier to solve this eqn. numerically, I was wondering how one would go about solving this analytically. I was trying to solve this eqn. with the following definitions and initial conditions : $$x_O(t) = \sin{(4\pi t)}$$
$$l = 0.2[m]$$
$$\theta(0) = 0$$
$$\dot{\theta}(0) = 0$$

So the eqn. that I have to solve would look like this: $$\ddot{\theta} + 5g\sin{\theta} = 80\pi^2\sin{(4\pi t)}\cos{\theta}\tag{1}$$

But because of my highly limited knowledge, I have hit a roadblock since I have no idea how one would solve a second order nonhomogenous differential eqn. involving trig functions.

During my search on the Internet, I found things like elliptical integrals, complementary functions and particular integrals but I did not quite understand how I should use them.

TL;DR: I would like to solve the second order nonhomogenous diff eqn. marked $(1)$ with the conditions mentioned above it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution to pendulum differential equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/653845/solution-to-pendulum-differential-equation)

Comment: I don't know if this one in particular can be solved analytically, but keep in mind that most non-linear differential equations can't be solved by hand. Sometimes a "partial" solution can be found, by lowering the order of the equation, or a full solution can be found but within the limits of an approximation (here it'd be the small oscillations approximation).

Comment: @RogerVadim I could try using approximations but I asked this question in view of how would one purely analytically solve the diff eqn. as it is. But thanks alot! :)

Comment: If you read through the answers to the linked question, they specify that only some non-linear differential equations are exactly solvable (and it very much depends on what one qualifies as an *exact solution* - do special functions count? Does a numerically tabulated solution count?)

Comment: The "duplicate" proposed by @RogerVadim doesn't involve the driving term, and so it seems to me that this question is fundamentally different.

Comment: @RogerVadim:  Sorry, didn't mean to offend.  But I simply don't think this question is close enough to that older one to be closed as a duplicate, and I wanted to offer a different perspective for those who might happen across it in the "close votes" queue.  I was under the impression that [this was acceptable behavior](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9818/a-way-to-mark-questions-as-non-duplicates/9819#9819) (see the third bullet point in the accepted answer there.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert *fundamentally* is certainly an exaggeration, and fingerpointing at me for suggesting that it might be a duplicate seems unnecessary as well. Apart from that, the point seems rather mundane.