# Deriving Harmonic Motion Period Length

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I have done the following work. Consider the following pendulum and measurements:

[image: Pendulum]

Assume the length of the pendulum is $r$. Then the following calculations can be done:

$h_{max} = r - r\cos{\theta}$

$U_g = mgh_{max} = mg(r-r\cos{\theta}) = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = KE \implies v_{max} = \sqrt{2g(r-r\cos{\theta})}$

We are solving for the period length, $T$. Consider the velocity vs. time graph of this pendulum. It will have the following equation: $v(t) = v_{max}\sin{\frac{\pi t}{T}}$ (I got this by letting one period of the sin graph be $2T$, since one swing of the pendulum is half of the graph's period). It is known that the area under a velocity vs. time graph is equal to displacement, which, in this case, is $2r\sin{\theta}$. Therefore, we solve the following equation for $T$, giving us our answer:

$$\int_0^T v(t)dt = 2r\sin{\theta}.$$

Did I make a mistake in my reasoning? When I solve for $T$, I get $\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{\frac{r}{g}} \left( \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}} \right)$, which is not correct. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The time dependence of the displacement is not a sinusoidal function. As far as I know there is no simple solution for the dynamics of this kind of pendulum and the actual formula for the period is usually given as an infinite series. The sinusoidal solution is what we get if we linearize the potential.

Comment: @FlatterMann I see, that makes sense (it has to do with $\sin{\theta} = \theta$, right?). I apologize, I know pretty much no physics, but how would that affect the equations I use for this problem?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653845/123208